# How to pass char variable through sendkeys?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

```
Random rnd = new Random();
char supName = (char) (rnd.nextInt(26) + 'a');
supID.sendKeys(supName);
```

I have a supplier text area, if I put any character then it will show supplier suggestion based on input like google suggestion (eg. if I enter "a" then it will show suggestion of all supplier whose name start with A.)

I wrote above code for the same but it is not working with sendKeys.

I am beginner to selenium.

Comment: That's because you're declaring supName as a char variable, but the sendKeys function applies to a WebElement type, and you're using supName for both variables.  Declare your WebElement then use that variable to `.sendKeys(supName)`

Comment: Sorry, i do typo error while posting. i edited my question. 
My webelement is supID here.
thanks @BillHileman

Comment: What is the tag type of supID?  Is it input?  Is this, by chance, Appium (mobile app)?  Can you please show both the HTML code for the text input and the locator you are using to retrieve it in your original post?

Answer (score 1):

Convert char to string and then pass it to the `sendKeys` function:

```
supID.sendKeys(Character.toString(supName));
```